# mysql, как получить данные?

Tags: mysql, node.js

Есть проблема. Я пытаюсь с помощью mysql библиотеки для node.js получить данные вот так:

```
const names = dbConnection.query('sql query', (err, results, fields) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    return results;
});
```

Мне нужно что бы в константе names, были данные возвращенные функцией, но получается объект mysql, в котором дынные о подключении и т.д. и в котором нет ответа от mysql. Как правильно это сделать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Comment: нет, там эта проблема не описана.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать promise для этого.

```js
function getData(sqlrequest, successCallback) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            dbConnection.query(`${sqlrequest}`, (err, result, fields) => {
                if (err) reject(err)
                if (result) resolve(result)
            });

    });
}
const sql = 'SOME SQL'
const myData = await getData(sql)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли.